# set type Blob in CreateSQLQuery fluent Nhibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, blob

I wonder what kind I should pass to use blob type in fluent Nhibernate.

```
string insertSql = string.Format("insert into \"{0}\" (sbfotoint,NmArqBlob) values (?,?);", tableName);
var queryInsert = session.CreateSQLQuery(insertSql);
queryInsert.SetByte(0, entidade.SBlob);
```

What is my `SetType`, to use  `Byte[]` Blob?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IQuery.SetBinary` is used to set blobs

```
queryInsert.SetBinary(0, entidade.SBlob);
```